# laravel pagination , i used paginate not simplepaginate yet the output is simplepaginate

Tags: laravel

im new to laravel. im having trouble with the pagination. i used **paginate** not **simplepaginate** yet the output is simplepaginate.

```
public function index()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->latest()->paginate(3);
    return view('product.index',compact('product'));
}
```

this is in my page below endforeach and table

```
 {{ $product->links() }}
```

this is the output

**« Previous Next »**

Comment: have you checked the class type of `$products`? the docs say it should return `LengthAwarePaginator` https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Comment: object(Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)#333 (11) { ["total":protected]=> int(5) ["lastPage":protected]=> int(2) 

this is the output when i checked.

Comment: seems to be working fine. Have you tried customising the view? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view, you can publish the view with `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` to see what is actually get rendered